# Distinction between using .text and .value in VBA Access

Tags: vba, ms-access

I am passing the `textbox1.text` values into a query and sometimes into a string:

```
Dim combor1 As String
combor1 = comboReason1.Text
```

How do I know when I should put `combor1 = comboReason1.Value`?

Also, why do I need to set focus for a control to reference its property? That doesn't make sense to me.

Also, when I set `combor4 = comboReason4.Value` and the `.value` is null, then I get an error about invalid use of null.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

- ".text" gives you what is displayed
  on the screen
- ".value" gives you the underlying
  value

Both usually give the same result, except when the corresponding control is

1. a combobox or listbox control
2. the displayed value differs from the bound column

Example:

- id_Person is a combobox control in a form
- the rowsource is "SELECT id_Person, personName FROM Tbl_Person"
- column widths are "0cm;3cm"
- bound column is 1

In this situation:

- id_Person.text displays Tbl_Person.personName
- id_Person.value displays Tbl_Person.id_Person.

.text property is available only when the corresponding control has the focus.

.text is a string value, therefore it cannot be Null, while .value can be Null

EDIT: .text can only be called when the control has the focus, while .value can be called any time ...

Comment: Note also that .text is limited to 2048 characters, while .value can have as many as 60k characters.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the `Text` property to set or return the text contained in a text box or in the text box portion of a combo box.

To set or return a control's `Text` property, *the control must have the focus*, or an error occurs. To move the focus to a control, you can use the SetFocus method or GoToControl action.

You can use the `Value` property to determine or specify if a control is selected, the selected value or option within the control, the text contained in a text box control, or the value of a custom property.

The `Value` property returns or sets a control's default property, which is the property that is assumed when you don't explicitly specify a property name. In the following example, because the default value of the text box is the value of the Text property, you can refer to its Text property setting without explicitly specifying the name of the property.

```
Forms!frmCustomers!txtLastName = "Smith"
```

**Text Property Reference**
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa173453.aspx

**Value Property Reference**
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa173476.aspx

Answer (score 0):

`.text` starts the field validation and causes an error if field validation is hurt. `.value` doesn't start the field validation, you may enter ANY value

Answer (score 0):

This thread and the answers herein explain the issue well. There are a couple of additional points I'd like to add, which I've found through experimentation:

The order of precedence of the properties is:

1. `.ControlSource`
2. `.Value`
3. `.Text`

From what I've been seeing in Access 2007, if `.ControlSource` is undefined when the form opens, `.Value` will be `Null`.

If you set the `.ControlSource` property to `=""` (an empty string), that will cause the `.Value` property to default to that instead of `Null`.

You can set the `.Value` property to `""` in the `Form_Load` event. But...I've been seeing some erratic operation there; it seems as if `.Value` sometimes changes from `""` back to `Null`, and I haven't yet worked out the circumstances.

So it seems best to define `.ControlSource` to `=""`, either in Design View or in the `Form_Load` event. But be forewarned, that niblet is tricky because of the embedded double quotes, and it can be tricky to read.

Some ways to do it are:

- myTextbox.ControlSource = "=" & """"" (five double quotes in a row)
- myTextbox.ControlSource = "=" & Chr(34) & Chr(34)
- Etc, etc, there are many ways to do it...

Also, here's an extended tidbit. If you set the `.TextFormat` property to `Rich Text`, you can format the text in it with bold, italic, colors, etc. But be forewarned (again), beginning with Office 2007, the original Microsoft RTF format was decommissioned in favor of a "mini" version of HTML that only supports a few tags related to formatting fonts and paragraphs.

As an example, say you want the textbox to display the little ASCII checkbox character with the word "valid" in italics next to it, and make it all green. You can do it, but it all has to be in HTML, and it's not easy to read:

```
myTextbox.TextFormat = acTextFormatHTMLRichText
myTextbox.ControlSource = "=" & Chr(34) & "<font color=#80CA45><font face=Wingdings>" & _
Chr(254) & "</font>&nbsp;<font face=Calibri><i>Valid.</i></font></font>" & Chr(34)
```

Answer (score -1):

If the text box is a ReadOnly control, the value property will not be used but if you set the text peoprty, the value will still be used in form data.