# ms-access: difference between .value and .text

Tags: sql, ms-access, vba

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [distinction between using .text and .value in VBA access](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2844193/distinction-between-using-text-and-value-in-vba-access)

i am passing values from a textbox into a sql statement in ACCESS

i do not understand the difference in the usage of these two properties

when i set the the .text property to something, how does the .value property get affected?
when i do want something to be displayed in the textbox should i be using the value or text property?