# Can a combobox present more then one column on its textbox part?

Tags: vba, combobox

I have a two column list in my combobox and when I choose one of the items in it using the drop down list, it stores (what I see in the textbox part of the combobox) only the value I selected (wether it's the one on the right or left column according to boundcolumn)

My question is: Is there a way to store(or present-that is my goal) in the textbox part of the combobox, both of the columns of one row selected?

For example: [column1] Daniel [column2] Smith. And in the textbox I want: Daniel Smith (and not just Daniel, or Smith on they're own)

Comment: Yes, there is a way to store it. Keep in mind, that your program has to know how to split the 2 cols up again (if you want to identifiy your dataset). Add a EventHandler for changed index and load the 2nd column in your text field.

Answer (score 1):

What you describe is theoretically possible, but with restrictions.

Even when you didn't ask for that, **here comes my idea**:

Like described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2844193/distinction-between-using-text-and-value-in-vba-access) you can change your ComboBox's `text` without changing its `value`. This allows you to 'store' the underlying value while displaying both columns in one.

Listen on the [`SelectedIndexChanged Event`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.office.tools.excel.controls.combobox_events.aspx) and change the `text` property as follows:

```
Sub ComboBox1_SelectedIndexChanged()
    ComboBox1.Text = ComboBox1.Column(0) & "-" & ComboBox1.Column(1)
End Sub
```

*(This is only a basic example.) Can't test it right now, but in .Net you can use `CType` to explicitly convert the `sender` argument to a ComboBox variable and access it this way.*

The `Boundcolumn` property can't be changed to multiple values. You can try to use `VbTab` as a delimiter in the text field but i'm not sure how it will appear.

**Edit:**

Don't forget the default values. I think your Text field should show both columns **before** the user clicked on the list the first time, too.

Answer (score -1):

You can set a combobox text field to use data from multiple columns but you may need to write some code to do it.

Try http://www.contextures.com/Excel-VBA-ComboBox-Lists.html

Comment: That's not what I meant. What I meant was to simply SHOW the two columns in the text area of the combobox BEFORE clicking on it. I wan't to see the two columns in the texbox area of the combobox and NOT only the drop down area. you know what I mean? -just to present the two columns of the active item in the textbox area.