# Combobox Event listener for dynamic user interface

Tags: vba, excel, combobox

I'm basically trying to display different sets of textboxes on a userform depending on the value taken by a combobox. I have created a class module call CControlEvents in which I describe the events that should occur when I change the value of the combobox :

```js
Private WithEvents mclsCbx As MSForms.ComboBox
Private mMyProperty As Integer

Public Property Set Cbx(ByVal clsCbx As MSForms.ComboBox): Set mclsCbx = clsCbx: End Property
Public Property Get Cbx() As MSForms.ComboBox: Set Cbx = mclsCbx: End Property

Public Property Get MyProperty() As Integer
    MyProperty = mMyProperty
End Property

Public Property Let Transition(Value As Integer)
    mMyProperty = Value
End Property


Private Sub mclsCbx_Change()

          'Options NUM
           Set Lbl4 = UserForm1.Frame1.Controls.Add("Forms.Label.1", "lbl3")
           Set txtB4 = UserForm1.Frame1.Add("Forms.TextBox.1")
         
           With txtB4
                 .name = "Unit" & mMyProperty
                 .Height = 15
                 .Width = 50
                 .Left = 500
                 .Top = 10 * mMyProperty * 3
                 .Value = "txtB4NUM"
           End With
            
           Lbl4.Caption = "Unité : "
           Lbl4.Top = txtB4.Top
           Lbl4.Left = 360
           
           'Options LIST
           Set Lbl3 = UserForm1.Frame1.Controls.Add("Forms.Label.1", "lbl3")
           Set txtB3 = UserForm1.Frame1.Add("Forms.TextBox.1")
         
           With txtB3
                 .name = "specMin" & mMyProperty
                 .Height = 15
                 .Width = 200
                 .Left = 410
                 .Top = 10 * mMyProperty * 3
                 .Value = "txtB3LIST"
           End With
            
        
           Lbl3.Caption = "Eléments : "
           Lbl3.Top = txtB3.Top
           Lbl3.Left = 360
        

    If (Me.Cbx.Value = "NUM") Then
        txtB3.Visible = False
        txtB4.Visible = True
    

    Else
        If (Me.Cbx.Value = "LIST") Then
            txtB4.Visible = False
            txtB3.Visible = True
           
        End If
    End If

End Sub
```

In the userform's code, I dynamically add such comboboxes :

```
'Create the combobox
Set oleCbx = Frame1.Add("Forms.ComboBox.1") 'Bug at this line

With oleCbx
    .name = "list" & i
    .Height = 15
    .Width = 100
    .Left = 70
    .Top = 10 * i * 3
    .AddItem "NUM"
    .AddItem "LIST"
End With

Set gclsControlEvents = New CControlEvents
Set gclsControlEvents.Cbx = oleCbx

Let gclsControlEvents.Transition = i
```

The problem is that when I change the value of the combobox, it displays the corresponding textboxes but it doesn't remove the others, whereas

```
If (Me.Cbx.Value = "LIST") Then 
txtB4.Visible = False 
txtB3.Visible = True
```

is supposed to set one of the textboxes to visible and the other one to invisible if the value of the combobox is "LIST".

**EDIT** : The correct solutions to this issue was given by @Rory in a comment.

Comment: Why do you want to add 2 new labels every time you change the value in the combobox?

Comment: This was just a mistake, each label is supposed to be attached to a textbox and therefore to be appear and disappear with it. @Rory

Comment: That's the problem then. You may hide the controls you add each time, but you don't hide the previously added ones. You should add them in the userform code and assign them to properties of the class, then you can simply hide/show as appropriate.

Answer (score 0):

Setting the txtB4.Visible = "False" should do it.  Maybe try to repaint the form.  Try these after the visible = "false".

```
UserForm1.Repaint
```

Or a doevents to let windows finish any updates.

```
DoEvents
```

If it is the value check that is failing, try the .Text property.

```
If (Me.Cbx.Text = "LIST") Then
```

.Text gives you what is displayed.

.Value gives you the assigned value to the list item.

[Distinction between using .text and .value in VBA Access](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2844193/distinction-between-using-text-and-value-in-vba-access)

Note the comment in that post about combobox.

Comment: So you are getting no errors, it just doesn't hide the txtbox? Are you sure the code is running through that section?

Comment: And do you know for sure that the line of code txtB4.Visible = False  is being reached?

Comment: Yes, I just tested it by adding a `MsgBox "Reached"` after it, I think Rory might have found the issue.