# How to enter multiple string variables into a text box

Tags: vba, excel

I have a workbook with an userform that captures user input into string and single variables and I want to display a text consisting those variables into a text box on the same userform using new line and tab.

Example:

```
Dim dog as String 'rex
Dim years as Single '5
Dim owner As String 'Joe
Dim address as String '123 Sample Street
Dim value as Single '300.00
```

I would like to have a textbox on my form,  that would display:

```
The dog's name is rex. He is 5 years old.

Owner:                    Joe
Address:                 123 Sample Street

Treatment value:   300.00
```

I used

`textbox.value = "The dog's name is " & dog & vbNewLine & vbNewLine & "Owner:            " & owner & vbNewLine & "Address:            " & address & vbNewLine & vbNewLine & "Treatment value:         " & value`

But after some time i will not be able to add another character to this line and I have plenty more variables mixed with text to come.

Can you suggest how this can be done?

---

Update: Resolved

Many thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try like this:

```
textbox.value = "The dog's name is " & dog & vbNewLine & vbNewLine & _
"Owner: " & owner & vbNewLine & _
"Address: " & address & vbNewLine & vbNewLine _
& "Treatment value: " & value
```

The " _" signs help you break the code into more lines. Note, that we have 2 signs - space and underscore there.

A small info - it is possibly good to consider passing the text as a `.Text` and not as `.Value`. Here is something good to read - [Distinction between using .text and .value in VBA Access](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2844193/distinction-between-using-text-and-value-in-vba-access)

Comment: the PO was not formatted, I think he want to have `VBTab` in between

Comment: Could be. But I think he is going to the end of the line of the VBEditor.

Comment: Thank you mate. Also + for the tip on .text vs .value.

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
textbox.value = "The dog's name is " & dog & vbNewLine & vbNewLine

textbox.value = textbox.value & "Owner: " & owner & vbNewLine

textbox.value = textbox.value & "Treatment value: " & value & vbNewLine
```

Continue with other fields!

Comment: Thank you Fabio, Works well, but Vityata's methods works better for me.