# Unable to retrieve value from Cells excel VBA

Tags: vba, excel

I am trying to activate a sheet from another sheet and display the cell value in a message box in excel but whenever i run it, there will be a subscript error, saying that subscript is out of range.

My code:

```
Sub Home()
Dim tbValue As String
tbValue = Worksheets("Home").TextBox1.Value

Worksheets(tbValue).Activate

MsgBox Cells(7,1).Value


End Sub
```

Anybody have any idea why subscript out of range ? Thanks

Comment: Does the sheet name you enter in `Textbox1` actually exist as a sheet? If it does try wrapping your Textbox1 value with a `TRIM` to get rid of any extra spaces at the end:  `Trim(Worksheets("Home").TextBox1.Value)`

Comment: Yeah it exists, I even tried hardcoding the sheet name instead of using tbValue but it is still the same error, run-time error 9, subscript out of range.

Comment: I don't think `TextBox1` can't be accessed like that. It has to be the sheet object like `Sheet1.TextBox1` or `Worksheets("Home").Shapes("TextBox1")...`

Comment: Which line does the error occur on?  My previous comment would have it occur on the worksheet activate line.  Does `tbValue` get a value correctly from `TextBox1`?

Comment: now it works, but it is empty even though the cell has a value.

Comment: Without qualifying the worksheet in `MsgBox Cells(7,1).Value` it will be using the currently active sheet - you may be reading the cell value from the wrong sheet.  @Vityata shows how to ensure it's looking at the right sheet with the `With... End With` block (or just putting the sheet name before `Cells`).

Answer (score 2):

Subscript is out of range because worksheet name is not found. It may happen in both `Worksheet(...)` line codes.

1. `Worksheets("Home")` may return subscript error because your active workbook may not be the one with your Home worksheet;
2. `Worksheets(tbValue)` may fail by same first reason and because tbValue may not match exact sheet name.

First solution may be ensure correct book is active:

```
Sub Home()
   Dim tbValue As String
   Workbooks("your_workbook_name.xlsm").Activate
   tbValue = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Home").TextBox1.Value
   Worksheets(tbValue).Activate
   MsgBox Cells(7,1).Value
End Sub
```

Better solution is to avoid sheet and books activations and use full qualified objects. If your macro is in the same book as Home sheet:

```
Sub Home()
    Dim tbValue As String
    tbValue = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Home").TextBox1.Value
    MsgBox ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(tbValue).Cells(7,1)
End Sub
```

You can also replace `Worksheets("Home")` with VBA assigned name to worksheet, probably `Sheet1` (you can check this name in IDE).

Comment: I usually set my wb and ws hardcoded as this: `Dim wb As Workbook Dim ws as Worksheet Set wb = Application.Workbooks("workbookname.xlsm") Set ws = wb.Worksheets("Sheetname")` then you can just reference like: `Msgbox ws.Cells(7,1)`

Comment: But why create a new variable when you already have objects created? `ThisWorkbook` is previously defined, and doesn't depend on file name, which you may change!

Comment: To avoid complications when multiple workbooks are open.

Comment: How `wb=Workbook("somename")` is less complicated then `ThisWorkbook`?

Answer (score 0):

The code looks workable, however, try the `With/ End with` and `Option Explicit` on top, it may work. Furthermore, it can be that .Cells(7,1) is an error or something. Anyhow, try again:

```
Option Explicit

Sub Home()
    Dim tbValue As String
    tbValue = trim(Worksheets("Home").TextBox1.text)

    with worksheets(tbValue)
        MsgBox .Cells(7,1)
    end with

End Sub
```

The idea for the `Trim` in the comments is also a good one.
Just to go one step further, use `TextBox1.Text`. See more here - [Distinction between using .text and .value in VBA Access](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2844193/distinction-between-using-text-and-value-in-vba-access)

Comment: Now the msgbox appears, but it displays nothing, seems like it is unable to retrieve the value of the cells in the sheet

Comment: What is in there? This is A7.

Comment: How would `Option Explict` and `With` solve an subscript out of range?

Comment: @LS_dev - well, at least it solved something, considering the fact that the error does not show any more.

Comment: But you are aware that `Option Explicit` is a compiler and option and `With` is just grammatic suggar. `Cells` is much different from `.Cells` and this may be the explaination.

Comment: `Option Explicit` is not a compiler. `With` is put there, to be closer to the code of the `OP`.

Comment: Real solution is `Trim`. All other is just confusing OP from real problem. `With` must be explained. And it is not the solution.

Comment: Anything is possible. I do not have access to the `OP` worksheet, just shooting randomly with best practices.