# Put predefined values, inside a USERFORM VB query

Tags: vba, excel

I am new to macro, but have some basic idea how it works or like able to write small VBA codes.

I have created a sample userform but i want to know how i can put values inside the code itself so that i dont want to maintain a separate lookup sheet to keep all those values for my dropdown option available under my USERFORM created.

Please find the code i used.

```
Private Sub cmdAdd_Click()
Dim lRow As Long
Dim lPart As Long
Dim ws As Worksheet
Set ws = Worksheets("PartsData")

'find first empty row in database
lRow = ws.Cells.Find(What:="*", SearchOrder:=xlRows, _
    SearchDirection:=xlPrevious, LookIn:=xlValues).Row + 1

lPart = Me.cboPart.ListIndex

'check for a part number
If Trim(Me.cboPart.Value) = "" Then
  Me.cboPart.SetFocus
  MsgBox "Please enter a part number"
  Exit Sub
End If

'copy the data to the database
'use protect and unprotect lines,
'     with your password
'     if worksheet is protected
With ws
'  .Unprotect Password:="password"
  .Cells(lRow, 1).Value = Me.cboPart.Value
  .Cells(lRow, 2).Value = Me.cboPart.List(lPart, 1)
  .Cells(lRow, 3).Value = Me.cboLocation.Value
  .Cells(lRow, 4).Value = Me.txtDate.Value
  .Cells(lRow, 5).Value = Me.txtQty.Value
'  .Protect Password:="password"
End With

'clear the data
Me.cboPart.Value = ""
Me.cboLocation.Value = ""
Me.txtDate.Value = Format(Date, "Medium Date")
Me.txtQty.Value = 1
Me.cboPart.SetFocus

End Sub

Private Sub cmdClose_Click()
  Unload Me
End Sub

Private Sub UserForm_QueryClose(Cancel As Integer, CloseMode As Integer)

  If CloseMode = vbFormControlMenu Then
    Cancel = True
    MsgBox "Please use the Close Form button!"
  End If
End Sub

Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()
Dim cPart As Range
Dim cLoc As Range
Dim ws As Worksheet
Set ws = Worksheets("LookupLists")

For Each cPart In ws.Range("PartIDList")
  With Me.cboPart
    .AddItem cPart.Value
    .List(.ListCount - 1, 1) = cPart.Offset(0, 1).Value
  End With
Next cPart

**For Each cLoc In ws.Range("LocationList")
  With Me.cboLocation
    .AddItem cLoc.Value
  End With
Next cLoc**

Me.txtDate.Value = Format(Date, "Medium Date")
Me.txtQty.Value = 1
Me.cboPart.SetFocus

End Sub
```

[I learn how to set this userfrom from a web site and you can use this link to download the sample excel file (posted on that website)](http://www.contextures.com/PartLocDBCombo.zip)

Kindly help me on this.

Thanks in Advance

Comment: you are already setting a control value with this line `Me.cboPart.Value = ""` .... just use the same kind of code to set a value that is not blank

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lets say you want to add some predefined locations, in the `UserForm_Initialize` sub, instead of writing...

```
For Each cLoc In ws.Range("LocationList")
  With Me.cboLocation
    .AddItem cLoc.Value
  End With
Next cLoc
```

...change it to

```
With Me.cboLocation
    .AddItem "Location 1"
    .AddItem "Location 2"
    .AddItem "Location 3"
    'Keep going as many as you like
End With
```

Comment: Thanks Rosetta, it worked well, will you help me one more thing, is it possible to use these values to save the excel file I have. If you can help me on this it will be great.

Comment: Sure. To put the selected location in the combo box into Excel spreadsheet range, say cell A1, is `Range("A1") = me.cboLocation.value`

Comment: Thanks, But the values we capture using a userform, how to get those value on a module we created, For example I select a value under 'cboLocation' from the UserFomr I created and I add a button, If user click on it which call MODULE 1 where the code is `SUB Try1 () Dim location Location = cbolocation MsgBox Location END SUB`. I tried this but I am getting null value under msgbox.

Comment: i think `Location = cboLocation.value` would solve the issue?

Comment: fyi there is difference between `.text` and `.value` for combobox, see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2844193/distinction-between-using-text-and-value-in-vba-access

Comment: I tried both .VALUE and .TEXT `Sub Try1()
 Dim Location
  Location = cboLocation.Text
 MsgBox Location
 End Sub `   not working RUNTIME ERROR 424 OBJECT REQUIRED, any one have a solution for this ?

Comment: i suggest u start a new question as usually ppl dont follow extensive comments