# Warning message in Excel macro if combobox null

Tags: vba, excel, combobox

I create combo box selection using userform in Excel macro.

What I want to do is, to prevent the user to click OK without selecting a value.
[image: Interface]

Here is my code, I don't know what is wrong, the message box doesn't show.

```
Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()
    ComboBox1.RowSource = "Sheet1!G1:G" & Range("G" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
    ComboBox2.RowSource = "Sheet1!G1:G" & Range("G" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
End Sub


Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
    If IsNull(ComboBox1) Then
        MsgBox ("ComboBox Has Data")
    End If

    Workbooks("Select Project.xlsm").Sheets("Sheet1").Range("B2").Value =  ComboBox1.Value
    Workbooks("Select Project.xlsm").Sheets("Sheet1").Range("C2").Value = ComboBox2.Value
End Sub
```

Can anybody help what is wrong with my code? Sorry, I'm new to VBA.

Comment: Do not test `IsNull(ComboBox1)` but `IsNull(ComboBox1.Text)`

Comment: the better way is to disable the OK button instead of popping a message

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're not checking the Text property of your ComboBox. You should process like this.

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
    If (ComboBox1.Text = "") Then
        MsgBox "ComboBox Has No Data"
        Exit Sub
    End If

    Workbooks("Select Project.xlsm").Sheets("Sheet1").Range("B2").Value =  ComboBox1.Value
    Workbooks("Select Project.xlsm").Sheets("Sheet1").Range("C2").Value = ComboBox2.Value

End Sub
```

---

### What changed ?

I changed `If IsNull(ComboBox1) Then` with `If (ComboBox1.Text = "") Then` so this will check the **Text** property in your ComboBox.

I also added `Exit Sub` to leave the function if the ComboBox is empty so it doesn't commit the operation after.

Answer (score 0):

`IsNull(ComboBox1)` and `IsNull(ComboBox1).Value` will both never be true. `Null` is a value returned from a database if a field contains no value. You have to check if the `value` of the ComboBox is empty. An empty string in VBA is a string with the length 0, so you have to use on of those:

```
If Me.ComboBox1 = "" then ...
If Me.ComboBox1.Value = "" then ...
If Me.ComboBox1.Text = "" then ...
```

(For the difference between `value` and `text`-property see [Distinction between using .text and .value in VBA Access](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2844193/distinction-between-using-text-and-value-in-vba-access))

Anyhow, I would go for the solution to enable/disable the button (as *Rosetta* suggested). Put a event-routine to the Combobox:

```
Private Sub ComboBox1_Change()
    Me.CommandButton1.Enabled = Me.ComboBox1.Value <> ""
End Sub
```