# Access VBA's Listbox.Requery command clears ListItems

Tags: sql, vba, ms-access, listbox, ms-access-forms

I have an Access form where I want users to select an AwardNumber. When they select the award, the associated documents for that award show up in either the Incomplete or the Complete listbox. Then I want them to be able to move items from one list to the other. The ListBoxes are single select.

[image]

**Here's the backend:** 
The Incomplete ListBox (says Unbound in design) has 3 columns. The Bound column is 1, but the 1st and 3rd columns have 0 width and are thus hidden. The listbox also has the following RowSource:
`SELECT DocTbl.DocID, DocTbl.DocTitle, DocTbl.DocLink
FROM DocTbl
WHERE ((DocTbl.Complete <> Yes) AND (DocTbl.AwardNumber = Forms!Select_Doc_To_Code!Award_CBox.Text)) 
ORDER BY DocTbl.DocID`

(The Complete ListBox has the same, except instead of `DocTbl.Complete <> Yes`, it has `DocTbl.Complete = Yes`.)

When they select the AwardNumber in the ComboBox, there's some VBA that runs the following to populate the lists, which works as expected: 
 
`Me.Incompletes.Requery
Me.Completes.Requery`

The two buttons trigger code to "move" the items. Here's the code for the top button that's meant to "move" the document from the Incompletes to the Completes listbox (i.e. by setting the doc's "Complete" value to Yes and then requerying the listboxes). The indicated lines are where things go wrong:

```
Sub Move_To_Complete_Click()
  docID = Incompletes.Column(0, Incompletes.ListIndex)

  Set Tbl = CurrentDb.TableRefs("DocTbl")
  Set db = CurrentDb

  db.Execute = "UPDATE DocTbl " & _
  " SET DocTbl.Complete = Yes " & _
  " WHERE DocTbl.DocID = " & docID

---->Me.Incompletes.Requery
---->Me.Completes.Requery
End Sub
```

In other words, the UPDATE query works (I see the updated data in the table), but when I try to requery both ListBoxes to refresh them, **all the items disappear** from both!. Further, if I select another Award from the ComboBox, and then reselect the **same** Award, the lists populate correctly again, ***just by running the same .Requery commands!*** 
I've tried `Me.Refresh`, `Me.Recalc`. I've also tried setting the RowSource again. I wonder if it's requerying too early; I've put breakpoints and DoEvents, so I don't think it's a timing thing, but maybe more of a code-needs-to-stop-running-for-requery-to-work. Which makes no sense because requery *is* code.
I know there are other ways to do this (I've tried and failed with those), but I'd really like to know why THIS way isn't working.
Thanks in advance!!

Comment: Why are you using the .text property of the combobox instead of .value in your listbox rowsource?  Try rewriting it using .value. If .value doesn't work, try using .column(0)

Comment: I had found that somewhere and the query worked. I.e., the listboxes populate with the right info. they just don't populate after the requery. For what it;s worth, I've tried .value (didn't work). Can you use .Column syntax in a rowsource query? How would I write that?

Comment: What happens when you modify your query by changing `Forms!Select_Doc_To_Code!Award_CBox.Text` to simply `Forms!Select_Doc_To_Code!Award_CBox`?  Do the `Requery` steps work correctly then?

Comment: @AlexSilverman .Text vs .Value in vba: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2844193/distinction-between-using-text-and-value-in-vba-access

Comment: Thanks, DataWriter. I was confused because it seemed like you were suggesting modifying my VBA code. But I only referenced the Award_CBox.Text in the RowSource of the ListBox control, not in the VBA code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're using the `.Text` property, and like DataWriter suggests, you shouldn't.

The `.Text` property is only available when a field has focus (see [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa173453.aspx)).

Because you're calling it in the `OnClick` event for the `Move_To_Complete` button, that button has focus, and so the `.Text` property is unavailable.

Two workarounds:

1. Use `Award_CBox.SetFocus` before you're requerying
2. Use `Forms!Select_Doc_To_Code!Award_CBox.Value` to  use the value property. Note that this assumes the bound column is the same as the column being displayed.

Comment: Thanks so much for the explanation. I thought I had tried .value before and it didn't work. Both `Award_CBox.Value` and just `Award_CBox` (as HansUp suggested) worked for the RowSource queries. I went with the latter because it was simpler, but `Award_CBox.value` still worked, even though my bound column is not being displayed...i.e. it's hidden with a 0" column width.