# Looping through select userform controls to print values in sheet

Tags: excel, vba

**NEW UPDATE-Using a Collection to Map Destinations of Userform Controls**

**Using a collection to reference userform controls and the location to input**

I created a collection, as shown below to reference the position to print the userform controls, to the sheet. I tested this on a sheet "Sheet1" with the controls being "subTaskID" and "TextBoxsubtask".

I get a

> "*ByRef argument type mismatch*"

on the ctlMap variable. I tried to follow PeterT's explanation below.

```
'' COLLECTION START DELETE FROM HERE IF WRONG
Sub Userform_Intialize()

Set ctlMap = New Collection
With ctlMap
    .Add item = "Sheet1!B1", key:="SubTaskID"
    .Add item = "Sheet!B2", key:="TextBoxsubtask"
End With

End Sub 

'Macro to populate sheet

Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()

    Dim ctl As Variant
    For Each ctl In Me.Controls
        If ControlExists(ctlMap, ctl.Name) Then
            Range(ctlMap(ctl.Name)) = ctl.Value
        End If
    Next ctl

End Sub
```

**Original QUESTION**

I have a userform to populate an Excel file regarding project tasks.

I created code linking each control to the correct column and cell number. I would like to be more efficient in my code to speed things up. I do not want labels, and certain textbox values to be inputted and also if a control is blank to skip to the next.

I can't order the loop through the controls correctly as it does not print in the desired cells.

How do I rearrange this order? Also how to I prevent it from printing false for an empty value?

I created an array with the required control names, however I get an error

> same object required when running.

```
lastrowST = subtaskws.range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).row

Dim Ctrl As Control, col As Long, range As range, userformorder As Variant

With AddTask
userformorder = Array(.SubTaskID, .TextBoxsubtask, .ComboBoxDeliverableFormat, .TextBoxcheckedcomplete, .TextBoxformat, .TextBoxacceptancecriteria, .BudgetWorkloadTextBox, .AWLTextBox, .ComboBoxOwner, .TextBoxTDSNumber, .TextBoxMilestone, .TextBoxTargetDeliveryDate, .ComboBoxW, .ComboBoxI, .ComboBoxe, .TextBoxP, .TextBoxLevel, .TextBoxInputQuality, .TextBoxNewInput, .TextBoxDelay, .TextBoxInternalVV, .TextBoxReviewer, .TextBoxDelivered, .ComboBoxNumIterations, .ComboBoxAcceptance, .ComboBoxProgress, .ComboBoxStatus, .ComboBoxFlowChart, .TextBoxActivitySheet, .TextBoxEvidenceofDelivery, .TextBoxComments)

For Each range In subtaskws.range("A" & lastrowST + 1 & ":AE" & lastrowST + 1 & "")
    For Each Ctrl.Value In userformorder
        If Ctrl.Value <> "" Then
            range.Value = Ctrl.Value
        Else
        End If
    Next Ctrl
Next range
End With
```

Comment: Looks like your loops are the wrong way round. What is `col` supposed to do?

Comment: col is just the column counter, so moves column. it is redundant now

Comment: i have updated wuestion

Comment: Does your array contains names of controls?

Comment: Yes, they are the names in the array

Comment: Where are the values supposed to go? As it stands you are likely to be overwriting.

Comment: The Values are inserted into the range along the new row, (lastrowST + 1).

Comment: So you don't care where they go?

Comment: No, i want them to be put in the correct columns, so assumed if looping through horizontal range it will go to the right? I have set up the array so that it is in same order as the columns needed.

Comment: OK, have posted an answer, would have been quicker if you'd mentioned that in your original question.

Comment: sorry i am new to this! appreciate it loads!

Comment: Please see original post, i havr updated the question with my current progress

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One method I often use creates a map between a control and a cell. I use a `Collection` for this and setup the map in the `Initialize` event:

```
Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()
    Set ctlMap = New Collection
    With ctlMap
        .Add Item:="Sheet1!B1", key:="TextBox1"
        .Add Item:="Sheet1!B2", key:="TextBox2"
        .Add Item:="Sheet1!B3", key:="CheckBox1"
    End With
End Sub
```

My userform looks like this

[image]

and the data on a worksheet looks like this

[image]

So now to populate the controls, it's just a loop through ALL the controls on the userform. Because we're using the controls map, only the controls that are mapped are populated. The `Select` statement is necessary because not all of the controls have the same property to access the data. For example, a TextBox uses `ctl.Text` but a CheckBox uses `ctl.Value`.

> **EDIT:** my memory was faulty and I referred to some older code of mine
>   for the example. [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2844288/4717755) provides a good explanation of why you
>   want to use `.Value` to access the values for the controls. This means
>   you could probably remove the `Select` statement and replace all of it
>   with a simple `ctl.Value = Range(ctlMap(ctl.Name))` to take care of
>   all assignments. Just in case the developer would like to perform
>   specific logic based on the control, I'll leave the `Select` statement
>   intact.

```
Private Sub PopulateControls()
    Dim ctl As Variant
    For Each ctl In Me.Controls
        If ControlExists(ctlMap, ctl.Name) Then
            Select Case TypeName(ctl)
                Case "TextBox"
                    ctl.Text = Range(ctlMap(ctl.Name))

                Case "CheckBox"
                    ctl.Value = Range(ctlMap(ctl.Name))

            End Select
        End If
    Next ctl
End Sub
```

> Or optionally
>
> ```
> Private Sub PopulateControls()
>     Dim ctl As Variant
>     For Each ctl In Me.Controls
>         If ControlExists(ctlMap, ctl.Name) Then
>             ctl.Value = Range(ctlMap(ctl.Name))
>         End If
>     Next ctl
> End Sub
>
> Private Sub ControlsToWorksheet()
>     Dim ctl As Variant
>     For Each ctl In Me.Controls
>         If ControlExists(ctlMap, ctl.Name) Then
>             Range(ctlMap(ctl.Name)) = ctl.Value
>         End If
>     Next ctl
> End Sub
> ```

The entire code for the userform is below

```
Option Explicit

Private ctlMap As Collection

Private Sub PopulateControls()
    Dim ctl As Variant
    For Each ctl In Me.Controls
        If ControlExists(ctlMap, ctl.Name) Then
            Select Case TypeName(ctl)
                Case "TextBox"
                    ctl.Text = Range(ctlMap(ctl.Name))

                Case "CheckBox"
                    ctl.Value = Range(ctlMap(ctl.Name))

            End Select
        End If
    Next ctl
End Sub

Private Sub ControlsToWorksheet()
    Dim ctl As Variant
    For Each ctl In Me.Controls
        If ControlExists(ctlMap, ctl.Name) Then
            Select Case TypeName(ctl)
                Case "TextBox"
                    Range(ctlMap(ctl.Name)) = ctl.Text

                Case "CheckBox"
                    Range(ctlMap(ctl.Name)) = ctl.Value

            End Select
        End If
    Next ctl
End Sub

Private Function ControlExists(ByRef thisCollection As Collection, _
                               ByVal key As String) As Boolean
    On Error GoTo SKIP
    ctlMap.Item key
    ControlExists = True
SKIP:
End Function

Private Sub CloseButton_Click()
    Me.Hide
End Sub

Private Sub PopulateButton_Click()
    PopulateControls
End Sub

Private Sub WriteButton_Click()
    ControlsToWorksheet
End Sub

Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()
    Set ctlMap = New Collection
    With ctlMap
        .Add Item:="Sheet1!B1", key:="TextBox1"
        .Add Item:="Sheet1!B2", key:="TextBox2"
        .Add Item:="Sheet1!B3", key:="CheckBox1"
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: @SJR thanks for the reminder. I've updated the code in the answer with an explanation.

Comment: Thanks PeterT, I am looking to use some of your suggestion to see if it speeds the process up! Can you loop put userform names in to an array and then lop through the array to save on specifying each case?

Comment: Use the optional version of `PopulateControls` and you won't need to specify each case. Just initialize the map collection when the form is created as in the example.

Comment: Sorry im confused, i was following the controls to worksheet function as i want the values from the userform into the worksheet

Comment: I updated the code above to show the optional `ControlsToWorksheet` sub without the `Case` statement. I'm less certain about your last comment though. Insert some `Debug.Print` statements to figure out what the `ctl.Name` and `ctlMap(ctl.Name)` values are. If they aren't what you expect, you should re-check how you initialized your map.

Comment: Thanks for your help Peter, really appreciate it! Just to clarify, if i was wanting to write the values inputted into the controls to the worksheet, would the set up of the collection look the same as your collection? Or would i tbe different as from what i understand from your exmaple is you are populating the controls from the worksheet, the reverse of what i am trying to do @PeterT

Comment: The code in my example works for both populating the controls from worksheet cells, and for writing the values of the form controls to the worksheet. You could use either one of those functions or both, depending on your design. If you don't want to populate the controls from the worksheet, then you can skip that method and just use the `ControlsToWorksheet` method.

Comment: Also, the additional code you posted in the question should probably be moved to a new question if you can't get it to work. You have at least one error in the `.Add item = "Sheet!B2", ...` line -- it should be `"Sheet1!B2"` (you're missing the `"1"`).

Comment: Your additional code also has a couple other problems. The statement to add items to the collection should use `Item:="...` and not `Item = "...`. This is a syntax error and the code will not run. Secondly, you MUST declare the `UserForm_Initialize` sub as `Private` or it will not execute. The `ctlMap` is not created unless the `Initialize` method is run. Other than that, after creating a simple userform using your (corrected) code and adding the `ControlExists` function, it works fine for me.

Answer (score 0):

I think this will do what you want. There is some good stuff in Peter's answer which would be worth perusing.

```
lastrowST = subtaskws.range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

Dim Ctrl As Variant, range1 As range, userformorder As Variant, col As Long

userformorder = Array("SubTaskID", "TextBoxsubtask", "ComboBoxDeliverableFormat", "TextBoxcheckedcomplete") 'etc

For Each Ctrl In userformorder
    If AddTask.Controls(Ctrl).Value <> "" Then
        subtaskws.range("A" & lastrowST + 1).Offset(, col).Value = AddTask.Controls(Ctrl).Value
    End If
    col = col + 1
Next Ctrl

End With
```

Comment: Thanks works amazing! peter's stuff looks good but i dont quite understand all of it!!

Comment: Question, how would get the code to skip certain columns, such as column 7

Comment: could i change the range to go up to column 7 and then start again at column 9

Comment: You could check the value of `col` and if it's 7 add 2 instead of 1.

Comment: You might want to start getting in the habit of accepting answers at SO if they help.